# Services (such as Twilo, Plivo, Nexmo) to verify phone numbers in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twilio, plivo, vonage

I'd like to verify phone numbers of user accounts in my Rails 4 app (by simply sending them a four digit pin number which they'll need to enter back into the app) - which services are available and which ones are the least hassle to implement into a Rails app?

I'd like to verify both mobile and landline numbers internationally, though my main areas will be Europe, the US & Canada, Australia and New Zealand (I am based in the UK).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your title lists three main SMS APIs, so for services available you already have a good understanding. But there are also APIs that focus exclusively on 2FA / Verification. Here is a [list of some](https://twofactorauth.org/providers/), worth noting that it tends to be focused on the user side of the equation (things like Google Authenticator).

Since **you ask about ease of integration**, a 2FA API (instead of an SMS API) may be far easier (you don't need to be concerned about generating a truly random OTP, or using voice fallback if the user does not respond to SMS, etc).

[Nexmo](https://www.nexmo.com/) (*Disclaimer: I work there.*) actually offers both SMS / Voice APIs, and a Verify API built on top of those lower level APIs.

**With our [Verify API](https://www.nexmo.com/verify/)** (it's going to be similar regardless of the 2FA API) you'd make a call to `https://api.nexmo.com/verify/json` and pass along `number` and `brand` (to identify your app) parameters. The response will contain a `request_id`, and once the user provides your app with the `code`, you'll pass both the `request_id` and `code` to `https://api.nexmo.com/verify/check/json`.

So it's 2 simple API calls, and in the interim you associate the `request_id` with the user's session. Here's a [quickstart on that process](http://nexmo.github.io/Quickstarts/verify/verify/).

With Nexmo specifically, if enough time passes without the second API call, the code is sent again, this time with a voice call (or, if the number is a fixed line, just starts with voice).

**With our [SMS API](https://www.nexmo.com/product/messaging/)** (again, will be similar regardless of the API) first you'll generate a code - which may sound deceptively simple, if security is a concern you'll need to ensure that the generation is truly random.

Then you'll store the code and [send an SMS](https://nexmo.github.io/Quickstarts/sms/send/). With Nexmo, that'd be a call to `https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json` with the `text` of your message, the `to` and the `from`*. There's also security concern there because you're storing the code on the same server as it validating it. If that's compromised, the verification flow is as well.

Finally, you'll compare the user provided code to the code you stored.

So **the least hassle** really depends on you. Is it easier to  make two API calls and avoid secure code generation / storage (and potentially get voice fallback for free)? Or DIY the code generation and reduce your integration to a single call to an SMS API?

Comment: Thanks Tim. I think for me the SMS API is fine. My only concern is bots - what if they sign up and put invalid numbers in and the system requests verification - do services like Nexmo only charge for valid/delivered SMS messages?

Comment: @A4J On the SMS API you're charged for each SMS (generally true for all SMS APIs). If the number itself is invalid, then you wouldn't be charged anything. For Verify, you're only charged for a successful verification (user provides the correct code).

Comment: Thanks Tim - do you know of any guides or gems to help integrate Nexmo with a Rails app?

Comment: @A4J Not a guide, but this ruby client library should be helpful: https://github.com/timcraft/nexmo

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You absolutely can use Twilio (or any of those other services) to verify phone numbers. There is a [good blog post here](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/01/12/phone-verification-using-twilio.html) that explains the steps you can go through to perform a phone verification via SMS.

As you are looking to verify landline numbers too, you might need to add voice confirmation too, where you call a user up and read out the 4 digit passcode instead. That can be accomplished in a similar way, but by making an outgoing call to the phone number which reads out the individual code using [Twilio's text to speech `<Say>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say).

Let me know if this helps at all. I'm in the UK too, so do reach out if I can help further.

Comment: Thanks for the info Phil - I'll check out the link. Do you still have a startup offer ($133.70 in Twilio credit) that Danielle mentions in the Quora thread? Twilio seems more expensive than the others :/